# How can I attach a Custom Tab to a Docusign Envelope?

Tags: docusignapi, docusignapextoolkit

Looking through the Docusign API documentation I am unable to figure out how to attach a Custom Tab to an Envelope. Using the traditional tabs sometimes forbid me from setting the text. Hence, the need for a Custom Tab. Using the CustomTabsAPI I can create a Custom Tab. What remains is the ability to attach the Custom Tab to the envelope.

> You can add custom tabs to envelopes and templates by setting the
> customTabId property when creating an envelope, template recipient, or
> when adding a new tab for an existing recipient.

I am using the `EnvelopeDefinition` to create my envelope.  I was expecting something like:

```
envelope_definition = EnvelopeDefinition(
        custom_fields=custom_fields,
        documents=documents,
        recipients=recipients,
        status='created',
        event_notification=event_notification,
        email_settings=email_settings,
        custom_tabs=custom_tabs # <------ SOMETHING LIKE THIS
    )
```

Any suggestions? An example of how to add custom tabs? Documentation? TIA

EDIT: Here is the textTab I currently have in place

```
signer = Signer(**args)
title_text = Text(
                anchor_string=anchor_string, 
                anchor_units="pixels", anchor_y_offset="10",
                anchor_x_offset="0", width="180", value=initial_value
            )
signer.tabs = Tabs(text_tabs=[title_text])
```

[example img of text not editable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M11Fp.png)

[example img of custom tab this can be edited](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2DYL.png)

If I can get the TextTab to be edited, that would be great.

Comment: can you elaborate on "Using the traditional tabs sometimes forbid me from setting the text."? I am just wondering if there's something you're missing and you could use regular text tabs for your need.

Comment: In the case that title is incorrect, the aim is to make the Title editable. However, according to the Docusign documentation: "A title tab displays the recipient's title. This value can't be set." I would like the ability to 'set' the title if incorrect. Hence, I've resorted to using CustomTabs where I'm having trouble attaching the custom tab to the envelope. @InbarGazit

Comment: If somehow I could avoid using the CustomTab and use the TextTab instead that would be great! You may be correct in suggesting that I may be missing an argument that makes the TextTab editable.  Although, currently I have no idea what the missing argument/option is? @InbarGazit

Comment: textTab is editable. Unless you make it readonly. By default - it should be editable. Can you share the code you're using with textTab so I can see why it doesn't work for you

Comment: updated OP to contain requested code @InbarGazit

Comment: is the code you pasted produces the image you had? I'm finding it strange. 
Try to have this:
x_postion = "100",
y_position = "100",
value = "test123",
required = "true",
page_number = "1",
document_id = "1",
locked = "false",
recipient_id = your_recipient_id

Comment: note that by using anchor strings, you are not creating a single tab, you created many of them, and won't be able to know which one you're looking for value. You may need to use x/y positioning for this one.

Comment: you may not need recipient_id actually if you do that when you initially create the envelope

Comment: Thanks @InbarGazit 
The missing argument you pointed me to was `locked="false"`.
I can now use a TextTab in place of the TitleTab (which is not editable).
Adding the `locked="false"` allows me to edit the text.

However, I am still curious how I would add a CustomTab to the envelope?

Comment: I am uncertain how to grant you credit for your assistance. Although your comments don't exactly answer my question, your assistance provided me a workaround which I am entirely thankful and grateful for.  Thank you very much @InbarGazit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summary of the solution:

The `title` tab is a system tab so the value can't be set.

Instead, the OP will use a `text` tab, set its value, and set the attribute `locked` to `false` to enable the signers to update it.